# Unexpected output in C code

Tags: c, for-loop, scope, initialization, declaration

The following code prints `AA`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i;i;i--)
        printf("A");
    return 0;
}
```

Why the initial value of variable `i` is `2`, and not some garbage value?

Is the lifetime of variable `i` static or automatic?

Comment: 2 is a garbage value.

Comment: @chux How can you be sure?

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior for using the value of an object with **automatic storage duration** while it is uninitialized.

Comment: @Coder With UB, any value is candidate garbage for an `int`.  (including a trap)

Comment: @chux Garbage values appear randomly. But if you run this code multiple times, initial value of a variable will always be 2. How?

Comment: "Garbage values appear randomly" is not true.  Undefined behavior is Undefined behavior. "run this code multiple times" is hardly _always_.

Comment: @chux It was intended to be a joke.

Comment: @Coder Going for [top billing](https://m.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/22rl06/til_in_vaudeville_the_straight_mans_name_usually/)?

Comment: If you have gdb, try this: `start` the program. Type `watch -l i` to set a hardware watchpoint at `i`'s location. Type `run` to restart the program. Look at all the points where the functions called before main touch that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the variable `i` is the entire for-statement (including its body). It has the automatic storage duration and will be destroyed after exiting the loop. You may not declare it as having the static storage duration as for example

```
for(static int i;i;i--)
    printf("A");
```

As the variable `i` was not initialized it has an indetermined value that can be a trap value.

Comment: If it is a trap value ,  would it still cause UB ?

Comment: @ameyCU Yes it can result in exception.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the variable `i` is not initialized. This means that the behavior of the implementation is undefined. And value of `i` is garbage value only. Here it is `2`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the edit.